# function (Crawler $node) symfony issue with using values

Tags: php, symfony, dom

The below code with get the a url, web contents (the helper isn't here but basic cURL with Guzzle) the uses Dom crawler to find content on page like link or contents in side  tags.  Because the crawler Function (Crawler $node) looping through, it being function means I can't use values for created for a new JsonResponse or in anyway outside that function and returns 
               The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget        to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?

```
  namespace AppBundle\Controller;

 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
 use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{

public $use;
public $item;
public $price;
public $link;
public $code;

/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */

public function indexAction()
{


    $html = $this->container->get('webscraper.helper')->contents('url');

    $crawler = new Crawler($html['html']);

    $crawler->filter('div.product')->each(function (Crawler $node) {

            $item =  $node->filter('h3')->text(); 

            $price =  $node->filter('p')->text(); 

            $link = $node->filterXPath("//a/@href")->text();

                    $secondpage = $this->container->get('webscraper.helper')->contents($link);

                   // echo $secondpage['size'];

                    $crawler2 = new Crawler($secondpage['html']);

                    $description = $crawler2->filterXPath("//div[@class='productText']")->text();
    //   echo $size;


            $use[] = array('title' => $item,'size' =>'5' ,'unit_price' => $price,'description' => $description);


           });
   // because of above }); cannot access $use 
    return new JsonResponse($use);


    }


 }
```

Comment: according to this doc http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html it works with no errors, but sure someones gonna s***t all over my code,  that's not in reference to you Tim BTW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access variable inside Closure function you need to "import" it by adding `use (&$results)` see my snippet below

```
$results = [];

$crawler->filter(self::RESULT_SELECTOR)->each(function (Crawler $node) use (&$results) {
    // code here
}

return new JsonResponse($results);
```

For primitive types you need to force reference by prepending with `&` for objects it's enough to just pass variable name